# How to detect packets that are only from the local network and not from the ISP/internet?

Tags: networking, ip, tcpdump

I'm building a bandwidth monitor using JNetPcap(java version of libpcap/winpcap). I need to recognise packets within the home network so that I don' count them towards the total bandwidth used. I could check the source and destination of packets but for that I need to know exactly what kind of packets are possible on the home network.

Another way could be to use the inbuilt filtering capabilities provided by libpcap: http://jnetpcap.com/userguide/filter but I guess thats a question for stackoverflow.

So to put it succinctly: Can you list the different packets that are possible on a home network and the fastest/most efficient way to detect them by checking the packet contents?  In other words, can you help me build an algorithm for detecting packets on the home network?

Comment: Are you asking us to help you: A) build an algorithm for detecting packets on the home network B) how to build a wireshark display filter, or C) asking us how to use a JNetPcap API?  FYI, home networking is off-topic for the site.

Comment: Questions on the JNetPCap API are valid here? I was hoping for options A or C, I never intended B. @MikePennington

Comment: JNetPCap questions are on-topic for [so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm to detect whether packets are from or to a home network is pretty simple, since most home networks use a single private IP subnet behind Network Address Translation.

Simply look at the NIC of the home PC, and use the netmask to calculate their IP subnet.  Packets with an IP address from that subnet are from the "home network".

Comment: Not exactly. what's intresting here is to filter-out anything which does not concern the gateway, be it source or destinationa ddress.

Comment: @Kwaio, could you elaborate specifically on how this does not answer the OP's question?

Comment: My bad, I've mistaken how NAT works for a moment. please ignore my comment.

Comment: The only way I can see to read the source or destination of a packet is to read the raw header contents. 
From the header, I can learn the source/destination if I know exactly where to look, i.e., I know what type of packet it is(ex: IP). So, will all packets in the home network be in the IP format?
Or is there a better way to learn the source and destination that I'm missing?

Comment: @JohnRoshan, you have to look at the source IP inside the IP header.  Even if you tried to only discriminate on mac-addresses, it is possible to confuse an ssh or http session with the default gateway with "WAN" traffic.